# How to have a textbox click event in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

```
 if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "txt2OnClick")
        {
            txt2_Click();
        }  

 txt2.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(txt2, "txt2OnClick")); //within page load 

private void txt2_Click()
    {
        ImageMap1.ImageUrl = "guide/2.jpg";
    }
```

This is a perfect piece of code to have a click event on textbox, with asp.net (C#). 
But the only problem is, we cant type when we apply this code to a textbox. So what I did was set the focus `txt2.Focus();` then I can type, but the textbox is **not getting validated** (I have added a regular expression validator) . **Any help?** Even to have a better onClick event for a textbox than this?

Comment: you want to validate when clicked or when write inside the textbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any point in having click event for text box.. Remove your 'perfect piece of code' and txt2 if not required..If you have added `regular expression validator` correctly, it will take care of validation..

**EDIT:**

For changing some text or showing some image, you don't need to post back to server..

You can either use javascript Focus event or jquery to do that..

In the link you provided, all those photos and texts are placed on `div`s and are already loaded on browser and when textbox gets focus, those div styles are just toggled between `none` and `block`..

Something like this([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saNBV/))..

Comment: I need the click event , so that an image in the imagemap will get change when I click on different textbox. I have already added the regular expression validator.But it doesnt works when I add this code to have the click event for the textbox.  [link](http://www.tailorstore.co.uk/measurement+profile?cmd=profile_m_b&type=26&gopage=login)  above link you can see when user click on a textbox the image changes. This kinda effect I need.  Hope Your clear , why I need the click event and waiting for the answer ..